# Get data with firebase

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, addition

I am making a kids app on iOS. When I released it, I had a problem with advertising because of the IDFA fence, and I had to remove it from the application. I also use Firebase / analytics. Will I have the same problems as with advertising through a data collection, or can firebase / analytics be used in children's applications?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per the apple new guidelines for Kids category, you are allowed to use third-party analytics with limited permissions in kid's application.

*In limited cases, third-party analytics may be permitted provided that the services do not collect or transmit the IDFA or any identifiable information about children (such as name, date of birth, email address), their location, or their devices.*

Yes, you can customize your app requirements following Apple's guidelines more strictly.

Go through this in detail - https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/#kids-category